# PIC32CX BZ2 register names don't match documentation

Tags: microcontroller, pic, c, arm, microchip

Preamble: I use MPLABx 6.1, the compiler (XC32) is installed and functions correctly, the correct device (WBZ451 with PIC32CX) is selected and xc.h is included. I have about 15 years experience with a dozen of microcontrollers but nearly nothing with the PIC32CX. I kindly thank you all for not sparing the brain-juice and taking precious time to help me!
Having said that, I would like to hear from those who *have* worked with PIC32CX and who *know* how it's done - as opposed to ideas that are based on experiences with other controllers. Ideas don't work, the PIC32CX appears to be different. I ignore Harmony and other drag-and-drop coding "aids".

In the PIC32CX documentation the register names - following tradition - are called TRISA, LATA, PORTA etc. Normally there's a header with all these names defined, so we can consequently use the same names in our code. With the PIC32CX that is not the case. I can't find any header files defining any of these, instead I have seen a few like GPIOA_REGS->GPIO_ANSEL and so on.
These names are not listed in the [WBZ451 documentation](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/WSG/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/PIC32CX-BZ2-and-WBZ45-Family-Data-Sheet-DS70005504.pdf), not in the [programming specifications](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/WSG/ProductDocuments/ProgrammingSpecifications/PIC32CX-BZ2-Programming-Specification-DS70005461.pdf), not in the [developer's guide](https://onlinedocs.microchip.com/v2/keyword-lookup?keyword=BZ2_APP_DEV_GUIDE&version=latest&redirect=true), not in the [xc32 compiler user's guide](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/50001686J.pdf). Shockingly, they are not in any other documentation one would come across while learning about this device or the environment.

Question: how are developers supposed to work with this controller and access the registers if the standard registers are not defined and what's defined is not documented?

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for individual register definitions for `ANSELA`, `TRISA`, `PORTA`, etc. then unfortunately you're out of luck - they haven't been defined in the PIC peripheral header include files that way.

`GPIOA_REGS` is a pointer to a `gpio_registers_t` struct (which is itself defined in gpio.h). That pointer is 'hard-coded' by the PIC peripheral header include file for your specific MCU to point to the start of Port-A's registers at 0x4400_2200. Similarly for Port-B there's a `GPIOB_REGS` struct pointer which points to  0x4400_2300.
Inside that `gpio_registers_t` struct are all of the individual Port registers: `ANSEL`, `TRIS`, `PORT`, `LAT`, etc. all laid out in the order they're found in the hardware.
So `GPIOA_REGS->GPIO_ANSEL` is at 0x4400_2200, `GPIOA_REGS->GPIO_TRIS` is at 0x4400_2210, `GPIOA_REGS->GPIO_PORT` is at 0x4400_2220, etc.
These are the standard registers. They are defined according to the documentation, just not in a way which you like or are used to.

However if that really upsets you then there's nothing preventing you from defining your own set of GPIO port peripheral registers and using them in your code instead.
For example, to define `ANSELA` you'd do something like:
`#define ANSELA  *((volatile uint32_t *)0x44002200)`
and then use it in just the way you'd expect: `ANSELA = 0x1234;`.
Similarly for TRISA:
`#define TRISA  *((volatile uint32_t *)0x44002210)`
and all the rest.

Comment: It's not really that it upsets me. The problem is that I only know about the GPIOA_REGS name because I was digging in the gpio.h. But the controller has hmm what, thousands of registers? One major role of the documentation is to list and describe these. But if the header doesn't follow the naming convention, we are forced to dig up about 50 header files and make pages of notes in a notepad. I'm not upset, but almost. How do I look up the equivalent of the EVCTRL register? With grep?
It's not your fault, I'm thankful for your answer, but it feels like being in the wrong movie.

Comment: The movie is called "ARM"